# Why does open() fail and errno is not set?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, linux-kernel, errno

In my code `open()` fails with a return code of -1 but somehow `errno` is not getting set.

```
int fd;
int errno=0;
fd = open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
printf("errno is %d and fd is %d",errno,fd);
```

output is

```
errno is 0 and fd is -1
```

Why is errno not being set?  How can i determine why `open()` fails?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> int errno=0;
> ```

The problem is you redeclared `errno`, thereby shadowing the global symbol (which need not even be a plain variable). The effect is that **what `open` sets and what you're printing are different things**. Instead you should include the standard `errno.h`.

Comment: Also, don't do `errno = 0`. `open` will set it correctly anyway.

Comment: @Mr.32 That open call seems to be directly opening a `tty` device, typically associated with a console. I suspect the error message is EPERM.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't define errno variable by yourself. errno it is global varibale (aclually it's more complex than just varibale) defined in errno.h So remove you `int errno = 0;` and run again. Dont forget to include errno.h

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring a local `errno` variable, effectively masking the global `errno`. You need to include `errno.h`, and declare the extern errno, e.g.:

```
#include <errno.h>
...

extern int    errno;

...
fd = open( "/dev/tty0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC );
if ( fd < 0 ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "errno is %d\n", errno );
    ... error handling goes here ...
}
```

You can also use `strerror()` to turn the errno integer into a human readable error message. You'll need to include `string.h` for that:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

fprintf( stderr, "Error is %s (errno=%d)\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add this to your module: `#include <errno.h>`
instead of `int errno;`